# Osmdroid and OSRM best approach to continuosly calculate time and distance to destination

Tags: navigation, osmdroid, osrm

I'm using Osmdroid and selfhosted OSRM to create navigation app.
I'm thinking what would be the best approach to calculate distance and time to destination in real time. What obviously comes to mind first is to detect if user is getting closer to each road junction (node) and if distance is for example less than 10m substract that distance from total distance. What if user will take wrong turn and bypass specific road node ? My app is designed to use as least internet possible due to some reasons. Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"What if user will take wrong turn and bypass specific road node ?"

In such a case, Waze recomputes the route. I think this is the relevant solution.